# Cannot get values of all my checkboxes on a click event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox as below :

[image]

The code for that list is :

```
@foreach (extranetClient.Models.Classes.FonctionContact fonction in ViewBag.Fonctions)
            {
               string coche = "";
               if ((@Model.ListeFonctions).Any(c => c.IdFonction == fonction.IdFonction))
               {
                    coche = "checked";
               }                                                   
               <input type="checkbox" @coche id="checkbox" value="@fonction.IdFonction" />@fonction.LibelleFonction <br />
            }
```

So now I would like to get the values of all the ckeckboxes which are checked in the list  everytime I check one of them. So I've tried that :

```
$("#checkbox").click(function () {
     var TabIdFonctions = new Array();
     var compteur = 1;
     $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(
        function () {
            TabIdFonctions[compteur] = $(this).val();
            compteur++;
        });
 });
```

But it doesn't work and I don't really know why. Hope somebody has an idea.

Comment: Quick question, don't you think ID's should be unique?

Comment: yes, it means that it's time for coffee. I'm sorry !

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML? I tried some sample code and working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/NKREc/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript arrays are 0 indexed. But you could use the `.push` method instead. Also you should use a class selector, not an id selector because you can have only one element with a given id:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
     var TabIdFonctions = new Array();
     $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
         TabIdFonctions.push($(this).val());
     });
});
```

Also don't forget to give your checkboxes a class, not id:

```
<input type="checkbox" @coche class="checkbox" value="@fonction.IdFonction" />
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript code

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.checked == true) {
        TabIdFonctions.push(el.value);
    }
}
```